# Is there a jQuery plugin which works like SO's vote message and tag tooltips?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Can anyone recommend an existing jQuery plugin that produces tooltips/boxes like these?

[image: Screenshot of desired functionality]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/). I use it on several of my work and personal projects, it's easy to use, supports HTML, and is fully customizable.

Answer (score 0):

qTip 35 kb to create tips is too big.

You simple only need create DIV to near DOM that you want.